# Angular not updating dom after array splice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a controller which has the test array and I have added 2 objects to it. When I call delete function from html ng-click, the array is not updated in dom but I can see that the array being spliced in js code. I have tried $apply(), but that does not work as it says it is already applied.

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', function($rootScope, $scope) {

    var person1 = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46}; 
    var person2 = {firstName:"Joe", lastName:"Horn", age:66}; 
    $scope.test = []; 
    $scope.test.push(person1);
    $scope.test.push(person2);

    $scope.deletePost = function(value, post){       
            $scope.test.splice(0, 1);
    }
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
 <div ng-repeat="tes in test">{{tes.age}}<br></div>
</div>
 <a data-toggle="modal" ng-click="deletePost(value, post)" data-target="#deleteModal"  ng-show="post.user.email == user.email" style="font-size:15px;margin-left: 1rem;" class="card-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Delete</a>
```

Comment: How do you call deletePost method ?

Comment: @Vincismique added in post now.

Comment: is "initiateDelete" supposed to be "deletePost"?

Comment: your code seems to work Perfectly. Check this plunker based on your code. https://plnkr.co/edit/w1QZ4OkaEHTKg3TSSBcH?p=preview

Comment: @Deep The original code is very large to be posted here, i guess there is some other problem.

Comment: this part of the code seems to work fine, can you create a plunker to replicate the issue ??

Comment: You transpose post/value and value/post here, maybe check for the order of parameters in the original code

Comment: I think the problem may be with ng-include as it is known to create new scopes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rearrange your dom and you also should splice based on index.

Try:

DOM :

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
 <div ng-repeat="tes in test track by $index">{{tes.age}}<br></div>
 <a data-toggle="modal" ng-click="deletePost($index, tes)" data-target="#deleteModal"  ng-show="post.user.email == user.email" style="font-size:15px;margin-left: 1rem;" class="card-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Delete</a>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', function($rootScope, $scope) {

    $scope.test = [{firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46}, {firstName:"Joe", lastName:"Horn", age:66}]; 

    $scope.deletePost = function(ind, post){       
            $scope.test.splice(ind, 1);
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `<a>` inside element which has your controller attached.

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
 <div ng-repeat="tes in test">{{tes.age}}<br></div>
 <a data-toggle="modal" ng-click="deletePost(post, value)" data-target="#deleteModal"  ng-show="post.user.email == user.email" style="font-size:15px;margin-left: 1rem;" class="card-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Delete</a>
</div>
```